# How to return a row vector containing the positional indices of a given number

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, row

Write a function in MATLAB called matrix_find_k that accepts a NxN matrix, m, and a value scalar value k and returns a row vector with the positional indices (i.e. (i,j) )of k within m. If the matrix doesn’t contain k, return an empty vector.

```
function rvector=matrix_find_k(m,k)
m=m==k
```

So far this is all I have. I don't know how to find the positions of all the ones that I have created in the matrix m.

Comment: Take a look at the [`find`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html#budq84b-1) function. That should help you on your way to a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution using the find function - it returns a vector containing the indices of the scalar value in the matrix and returns an empty vector if the scalar value is not found:

Example Script to call function:

```
%Example matrix
m = [1 2 3 4;
    5 6 7 8;
    9 10 11 12];

k = 3; % Example value to find

rvector = matrix_find_k(m,k)
```

Function:

```
function rvector = matrix_find_k(m,k)
    [i,j] = find(m == k);
    rvector = [i,j];
end
```

Example output: (example k=3 is in row 1 column 3 of matrix m)

```
rvector =

   1   3
```